# How to create a button which will stay on top of all window and can take click to open another similar overlay activity in android?

Tags: android, overlay, system, transparency

I am new at android programming. I have created a button using system overlay and a service. Now what I want is to click that button and get another overlay window of more 5 buttons. But the problem is that button doesn't take any click and don't allow me to open another overlay window. Here is the xml code I have used to draw the button--

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/l1"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context=".OverlayActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/mainButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAlignment="center" 
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:focusable="true">

</Button>
```

and here is the code I have used to show the overlay button

```
    @Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View oView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_overlay, null);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
            0 | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
             WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
             PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    wm.addView(oView, params);
    Button button = (Button)oView.findViewById(R.id.mainButton);


    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

           Toast.makeText(OverlayService.this, "GotCha!!! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    });
    ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup)oView.findViewById(R.id.l1);
    final Display  metrics = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
    vg.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
       switch(event.getActionMasked()){

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
             int x = (int)event.getX() - offset_x;
             int y = (int)event.getY() - offset_y;


             int w = metrics.getWidth()-100;
             int h = metrics.getHeight()-100;

             if(x > w){
                x = w;
             }
             if(y > h){
                y = h;
             }
             LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
             new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(
             LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
             LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));                
             lp.setMargins(x, y, 0, 0);
             selected_item.setLayoutParams(lp);
             break;

             default:
             break;
        }
        return true;
    }
});
    button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
       switch(event.getActionMasked()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                offset_x = (int)event.getX();
                offset_y = (int)event.getY();
                selected_item = v;
                break;
                default:
                    break;
       }
       return false;
    }
    });
}
```

Any ideas guys? I am running out of time..Please

Answer (score 1):

Better you use fragment for this

Comment: Can you please elaborate the concept with some details code? @ SIVAKUMAR J. I am running out of ideas. How can I create a fragment view to overlay over all the other window? I am Novice you know.

Answer (score 0):

Create views using fragments, overlay a button above the fragment.

Comment: Can you show me some example with the codes?@gandharva. I can't understand this concept. I need to know how to implement this concept. Please, any tutorials can also help.

Comment: I can explain the concept.

Suppose you have a root layout, say Relative Layout, which contains a FrameLayout (with full width and height) and a Button overlaid in top-right corner.

Now in the Activity class, you get hold of the FrameLayout and replace it with fragment1. If you need to change the screen, replace fragment1 with fragment2. And so on...

Refer http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html for more on fragment

Comment: What will happen if I want to keep that button movable like facebook chat icon on the screen? Can you suggest me on that?@gandharva

Comment: I know of a class that will be helpful in that scenario, it's ViewDragHelper https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/ViewDragHelper.html

Comment: Can you please provide me a example link from where I can understand the use clearly?